# Spring3 with Security and CAS

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am trying to use Spring3 with Security and CAS.  I am getting the following error.

Reason: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Can someone please tell me why? below is my xml file

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="serviceProperties"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <beans:property name="service"
            value="http://localhost:8081/Spring3MVCandHibernate3/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
        <beans:property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
        <beans:property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <beans:property name="ticketValidator">
            <beans:bean
                class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                <beans:constructor-arg index="0"
                    value="http://localhost:8080/cas-server-webapp-3.4.10/login" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="key"
            value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
    </beans:bean>


    <user-service id="userService">
        <user name="joe" password="joe" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL  you have specified for org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator bean should not have /login at end.

Its an old question; please let me know if that's how you fixed your error.